# Issue running cobertura with sonar

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, maven-3, maven-cobertura-plugin

While running cobertura with sonar (plugins installed in jenkins), i get the below error. The snippet in pom, error and other details are below. Can anyone please help on ? Thanks in advance.
**Maven version is 3.0.4.** 
After googling around got the solution to add the dependency in pom . Still it did not work
 **The goal used is clean install -U cobertura:cobertura sonar:sonar**

```
   java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.codehaus.mojo.cobertura.CoberturaReportMojo not present
at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:115)
at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load(NamedClass.java:46)
at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:133)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:260)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:252)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:459)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:97)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/reporting/AbstractMavenReport
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at      org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:389)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:107)
... 41 more
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
... 56 more
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------    ---
[INFO] Skipping -  List item

 IndexWeb
 [INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Reactor Summary:
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] IndexWeb .................................... FAILURE [1.325s]
 [INFO] IndexWeb-webservices ........................ SKIPPED
 [INFO] IndexWeb-service ............................ SKIPPED
 [INFO] IndexWeb-web ................................ SKIPPED
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time: 2.758s
 [INFO] Finished at: Fri Jun 19 06:39:11 UTC 2015
 [INFO] Final Memory: 12M/111M
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 **[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:cobertura (default-cli) on project IndexWeb: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:cobertura failed: Unable to load the mojo 'cobertura' in the plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6'. A required class is missing:   org/apache/maven/reporting/AbstractMavenReport**
  [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
  [ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6
  [ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
  [ERROR] urls[0] =    file:/home/jboss/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/cobertura-maven-plugin/2.6/cobertura-maven-plugin-2.6.jar
  [ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/jboss/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
  [ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
  [ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
  [ERROR] 
  [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------:      org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport
  [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
  [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
  [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
  [ERROR] 
  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
  [ERROR] [Help 1]   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
   Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
   Archiving artifacts
   Skipping sonar analysis due to bad build status FAILURE

     <-- The snippet of pom below -->

   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.6</version>
       <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.reporting</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-reporting-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.9</version>
       </dependency>
       </dependencies>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: In order to isolate the problem, could you just check that the problem is only with cobertura by removing the sonar:sonar goal  ?

Comment: when running with cobertura:cobertura it runs fine... But i want to see the coverage report on sonar dashboard ..So will it work to show the junit or code coverage report on sonar dashboard ?

Comment: Please try to use a more recent version of Maven since it may be caused by bad classloader isolation between plugins.

Comment: I did not see the date of posting :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, some tests are taking some time / hung for a while. It's a random failure.

In case you wanna proceed with the sonar analysis use this option

> -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true

This should ignore the failures and show you the results. Let me tell you in advance, that this is gonna help only for the seeing the analysis for the passed tests.

Just a thing, I had the same problem earlier. We found out that, it was something to do with the redis caching. We fixed it and it worked like a charm, then we removed the option which I've mentioned above.